# Streak builder app using Swift and SwiftUI

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

I am looking to make a Streak builder app using Swift and SwiftUI. However, I am finding it difficult to create the logic for the counter using the Date(). Any suggestions will be highly appreciated.

Mainly I wanna replicate the Streak thing from the Duolingo app.

```
// I have this extension to follow up on the Date from the time user clicks it.
extension Date {
    
    
    // for tomorow's Date
    static var tomorrow:  Date { return Date().dayAfter }
    static var today: Date {return Date()}
    var dayAfter: Date {
       return Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1, to: Date())!
    }
    
 
}
```

// More or less this was supposed to be my view.

```
struct StreakTrial: View {
    @State var counter = 0
    @State var TapDate: Date = Date.today
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack{
                Button {
//                    if TapDate != Date.today {
//                        counter += 1
//                        let TapDate = Date.tomorrow
//                    }
//                    else if TapDate == Date.tomorrow {
//                        counter = counter
//                    }
               
                } label: {
                    Image(systemName: "flame")
                        .resizable()
                        .frame(width: 40, height: 50)
                        .padding()
                        .scaledToFit()
                        .background(Color.gray)
                        .foregroundColor(Color.orange)
                        .cornerRadius(12)
                    Text("\(counter)").foregroundColor(.gray)
                }

               
                    
                Text("\(Date())")
                    .padding()
                Text("\(Date().dayAfter)")
                    .padding()
         
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: SwiftUI should have no involvement in calculating a `streak` SwiftUI is for UI therefore it should only be used for displaying and communicating user interactions with deeper parts of the code. Something like this is usually comes from a database that stores the days the user logged in, the days a user competed a task, etc. It isn't a plain counter.

Answer (score 1):

```
**SO I  TRIED SOME TUTORIALS OF @NICK SARNO WHICH GOES LIKE SWIFTFUL THINKING ON YOUTUBE AND GOT IT DONE**

*This code is compatible with Xcode 14.0*

import SwiftUI

extension Date {
    
    // for tomorow's Date
    static var tomorrow:  Date { return Date().dayAfter }
    static var today: Date {return Date()}
    var dayAfter: Date {
       return Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: 1, to: Date())!
        // just add .minute after byAdding: , to create a streak minute counter and check the logic.
    }

    static func getTodayDate() -> String {

           let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()

           dateFormatter.dateFormat = "E d MMM yyyy"
        //to continue with the minute streak builder just add "E d MMM yyyy h:mm a" above, it will allow date formatting with minutes and follow the changes in dayAfter

        return dateFormatter.string(from: Date.today)

       }
    
    static func getTomDate() -> String {
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        
        dateFormatter.dateFormat = "E d MMM yyyy"
        
        return dateFormatter.string(from: Date.tomorrow)
    }
}

struct StreakApp: View {
    
    @AppStorage("counter") var counter = 0
    @AppStorage("tapDate") var TapDate: String?
    @AppStorage("Tappable") var ButtonTapped = false
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack{
                VStack {
                    Text("\(counter)").foregroundColor(.gray)
                    Text("Restore your streak on ")
                    Text(TapDate ?? "No Date")
                    Image(systemName: "flame")
                        .resizable()
                        .frame(width: 40, height: 50)
                        .padding()
                        .scaledToFit()
                        .background(ButtonTapped ? Color.red : Color.gray)
                        .foregroundColor(ButtonTapped ? Color.orange : Color.black)
                        .cornerRadius(12)
                }
                Button {
                    if  TapDate == nil {
                        //Check if user has already tapped
                        self.ButtonTapped = true
                        counter += 1
                        self.TapDate = ("\(Date.getTomDate())")
                    }
                    else if ("\(Date.getTodayDate())") == TapDate {
                        //Check for the consecutive Day of Streak
                       
                        self.TapDate = ("\(Date.getTomDate())")
                        counter += 1
                        //Let's light the flame back again.
                        self.ButtonTapped = true
                    }
                    
                } label: {
                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 12, style: .continuous)
                        .foregroundColor(.black)
                        .frame(width: 120, height: 40)
                        .overlay {
                            Text("Add Streak")
                                .foregroundColor(.white)
                        }
                }
                .padding()
                //This button is only for testing purpose.
                Button {
                    self.TapDate = nil
                    self.ButtonTapped = false
                    self.counter = 0
                } label: {
                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 12, style: .continuous)
                        .foregroundColor(.black)
                        .frame(width: 160, height: 40)
                        .overlay {
                            Text("Reset Streak")
                                .foregroundColor(.white)
                        }
                }
          
            }
            //Ensuer the flame dies out if we run into any other day except today or tommorow.
            .onAppear {
                if ("\(Date.getTodayDate())") == TapDate ||
                    ("\(Date.getTomDate())") == TapDate {
                    self.ButtonTapped = true
                }
                //Breaking the Streak
                else {
                    self.TapDate = nil
                    self.ButtonTapped = false
                    self.counter = 0
                }
          
            }
        }
    }
}

struct StreakApp_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        StreakApp()
    }
}
```

Comment: If I were to do this in a ForEach with multiple buttons, how would I increase the streak counter of only the tapped button, not all of them. Currently all of them are being updated